# Why is the Pokedex glitching

Tags: pokemon-go

Whenever I want to view a Pokemon within my Pokedex and click on it the Pokedex rotates back to Charmander, which was my starter. Does anyone else have that glitch or knows a solution? Everything else seems to work properly

Update: this is how it looks like when I swipe

[image: off-centre Pokedex entry]

Update:
I have a Sony XperiaZ5 compact Android version 6.0.1
I tried restaring the app and the phone multible times. I also reinstalled the app, which also didn't fix the Pokedex.

Comment: Can you swipe the  screen to change the Pokemon that you're looking at?

Comment: Yes I can but the entrys are not centered and the Pokemon pictures are even more off

Comment: Could you show a picture of this? (Screen shot your device)

Comment: I added it to my question

Comment: Looks familiar. My Pokédex does the same.

Comment: What kind of device are you playing on? I've noticed this is a very common issue on android devices whereas it works fine on iOS devices

Comment: Sony XperiaZ5 compact Android version 6.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Niantic released v 0.31.0 for android on 7/30/2016

Beforehand the Pokedex glitched and scrolled, just as your described. After I installed the updated, I was able to load the Pokedex and view the Pokemon with no issues at all.

Comment: The new version fix it for me too.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue and it was due to my touchscreen not registering that I had removed my finger.

A restart of the phone resolved the issue.

It might also be worth clearing your cache or re-installing the app. You won't lose anything doing this, because all of your data is stored on your account, not your phone.

Comment: I turn my phone off over night so I already restarted my phone 5 times and it did not fix it. I now cleared my cache which also didn't help. I will try reinstalling the app as soon as I'm at home.

Comment: Didn't have any luck on my Samsung Galaxy S7.

Comment: I reinstalled the app but sadly this did not fix the pokedex glitch